Se deselecciona el producto en mi listbox cuando cliqueo en un spinbox
Tengo el siguiente código:
def crear_combo():
    cargar_datos()  # Cargar productos desde Productos.json
    
    # Crear una nueva ventana para crear el combo
    ventana_combo = tk.Toplevel()
    ventana_combo.title("Añadir productos al combo")
    ventana_combo.geometry("600x450")  # Establecer un tamaño más grande para la ventana

    # Lista para almacenar los productos seleccionados
    productos_seleccionados = []

    # Campo para filtrar productos por nombre
    tk.Label(ventana_combo, text="Filtrar por nombre:", font=("Helvetica", 14)).pack(pady=10)
    filtro_var = tk.StringVar()
    filtro_entry = tk.Entry(ventana_combo, textvariable=filtro_var, font=("Helvetica", 16), width=30)
    filtro_entry.pack(pady=5)

    # Mostrar los productos cargados en un Listbox con scrollbar
    lista_productos = tk.Listbox(ventana_combo, selectmode=tk.MULTIPLE, font=("Helvetica", 16))
    scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(ventana_combo)
    lista_productos.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    scrollbar.config(command=lista_productos.yview)

    # Agregar el Listbox y el scrollbar a la ventana
    lista_productos.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    scrollbar.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y)

    # Añadir los productos a la tabla
    for producto in productos:
        lista_productos.insert(tk.END, producto['nombre'])
  
    # Actualizar la lista de productos según el filtro
    def actualizar_filtro(*args):
        filtro = filtro_var.get().lower()
        lista_productos.delete(0, tk.END)  # Limpiar la lista
        for producto in productos:
            if filtro in producto['nombre'].lower():
                lista_productos.insert(tk.END, producto['nombre'])
    
    filtro_var.trace_add("write", actualizar_filtro)

    # Crear una nueva ventana para mostrar los productos seleccionados
    ventana_lista_productos = tk.Toplevel()
    ventana_lista_productos.title("Lista de productos para el combo")
    ventana_lista_productos.geometry("600x500")  # Establecer un tamaño más grande para la ventana

    # Establecer la posición de la ventana al lado de la ventana principal
    x = ventana_combo.winfo_x() + ventana_combo.winfo_width() + 1050 # Posiciona a la derecha de la ventana_combo
    y = ventana_combo.winfo_y() # Mantiene la misma altura
    ventana_lista_productos.geometry(f"600x450+{x}+{y}")  # Ajustar la posición

    # Espacio para ingresar el nombre del combo
    tk.Label(ventana_lista_productos, text="Nombre del Combo:", font=("Helvetica", 14)).pack(pady=10)
    nombre_combo_var = tk.StringVar()
    nombre_combo_entry = tk.Entry(ventana_lista_productos, textvariable=nombre_combo_var, font=("Helvetica", 16), width=30)
    nombre_combo_entry.pack(pady=5)

    # Mostrar los productos seleccionados
    tk.Label(ventana_lista_productos, text="Productos seleccionados:", font=("Helvetica", 14)).pack(pady=10)
    tabla_seleccionados = ttk.Treeview(ventana_lista_productos, columns=("nombre", "cantidad"), show="headings")
    tabla_seleccionados.column("nombre", anchor=tk.CENTER, width=300)
    tabla_seleccionados.column("cantidad", anchor=tk.CENTER, width=150)
    tabla_seleccionados.heading("nombre", text="Nombre")
    tabla_seleccionados.heading("cantidad", text="Cantidad")
    tabla_seleccionados.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

    # Botón para añadir el producto y la cantidad a la lista
    def añadir_producto():
        seleccion = lista_productos.curselection() # Obtener los índices seleccionados
        cantidad = cantidad_var.get()  # Obtener la cantidad seleccionada del Spinbox

        if not seleccion:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Por favor, selecciona un producto para añadir.")
            return

        # Recorrer los productos seleccionados
        for indice in seleccion:
            producto_seleccionado = productos[indice]
            producto_nombre = producto_seleccionado['nombre']

            # Verificar si el producto ya está en la tabla
            producto_existente = False
            for item in tabla_seleccionados.get_children():
                if tabla_seleccionados.item(item, 'values')[0] == producto_nombre:
                    producto_existente = True
                    break
         
            if producto_existente:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", f"El producto '{producto_nombre}' ya está en la lista.")
            else:
                # Agregar el producto y la cantidad a la tabla si no está duplicado
                tabla_seleccionados.insert("", "end", values=(producto_nombre, f"Cantidad: {cantidad}"))

        # Mantener la selección en la lista de productos
        lista_productos.selection_set(seleccion[0], seleccion[-1])

    boton_añadir = tk.Button(ventana_combo, text="Añadir", command=añadir_producto, font=("Helvetica", 14))
    boton_añadir.pack(pady=10)

    # Espacio vertical para separar el botón del Spinbox
    tk.Frame(ventana_combo, height=10).pack()

    cantidad_var = tk.IntVar(value=1)  # Valor inicial de cantidad
    spinbox_cantidad = tk.Spinbox(ventana_combo, from_=1, to=100, textvariable=cantidad_var, font=("Helvetica", 14), width=5)
    spinbox_cantidad.pack(pady=10)

    # Función para mantener la selección en la Listbox cuando se interactúa con el Spinbox
    def mantener_seleccion(event=None):
        seleccion = lista_productos.curselection()
        if seleccion:
            # Se reestablece la selección sin importar cuántos productos estén seleccionados
            for indice in seleccion:
                lista_productos.selection_set(indice)

                # Evento para evitar perder la selección en el Listbox
    def evitar_deseleccion(event):
        mantener_seleccion()  # Mantener la selección cada vez que el Listbox pierda el foco

    # Asociar la función mantener_seleccion al Spinbox
    spinbox_cantidad.bind("<FocusIn>", mantener_seleccion)

    # Asociar la función evitar_deseleccion al Listbox para cuando pierda el foco
    lista_productos.bind("<FocusOut>", evitar_deseleccion)

    # Crear un frame para los botones
    frame_botones = tk.Frame(ventana_lista_productos)
    frame_botones.pack(pady=10)

    # Botón para crear el combo
    def crear_combo_en_json():
        if len(tabla_seleccionados.get_children()) < 2:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Por favor, selecciona al menos 2 o más productos para crear el combo.")
            return
        
        nombre_combo = nombre_combo_var.get().strip()
        if not nombre_combo:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Ponle nombre al combo.")
            return
        
        combo_data = {
            "nombre": nombre_combo_var.get(),
            "productos": [producto['nombre'] for producto in productos_seleccionados]
        }
        for item in tabla_seleccionados.get_children():
            producto = tabla_seleccionados.item(item, 'values')
            combo_data["productos"].append({
                "nombre": producto[0],
                "cantidad": int(producto[1].split(": ")[1])
            })
            
        # Cargar los datos de Productos.json
        try:
            with open('Productos.json', 'r') as archivo:
                datos = json.load(archivo)
                if isinstance(datos, dict):  # Si datos es un diccionario, conviértelo a una lista
                    datos = [datos]
        except FileNotFoundError:
            datos = []
        
        # Agregar el combo a los datos
        if len(datos) > 0 and "Combos" in datos[0]:
            datos[0]["Combos"].append({"nombre": combo_data["nombre"], "productos": combo_data["productos"]})
        else:
            datos.append({"Combos": [{"nombre": combo_data["nombre"], "productos": combo_data["productos"]}]})

        # Guardar los datos en Productos.json
        with open('Productos.json', 'w') as archivo:
            json.dump(datos, archivo, indent=4)
        
        print("Combo creado:", combo_data)  # Simulación de la creación del combo
        messagebox.showinfo("Éxito", "El combo se ha creado correctamente.")

    tk.Button(frame_botones, text="Crear Combo", command=crear_combo_en_json, font=("Helvetica", 14)).pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=10)

    # Botón para eliminar el producto de la lista
    def eliminar_producto():
        seleccion = tabla_seleccionados.selection()  # Obtener los índices seleccionados
        if len(seleccion) < 1:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Por favor, selecciona un producto para eliminar.")
            return
        
        tabla_seleccionados.delete(seleccion)  # Eliminar el producto de la tabla

    tk.Button(frame_botones, text="Eliminar producto", command=eliminar_producto, font=("Helvetica", 14)).pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=10)

El problema que no logro solucionar es que se de-selecciona el producto en mi listbox cuando cliqueo en el spinbox. Lo que me gustaría es que se mantuviesen seleccionados los productos cuando hago doble click en el número de la spinbox, ya que luego al presionar en el botón añadir, se añadirían a la otra lista para crear el combo. Les muestro lo que pasa en un gif:

Pido ayuda por acá ya que he preguntado a varias personas y no se ha podido solucionar, así que pido ayuda acá para ver si alguien podría ayudarme, supuestamente me dijeron que con def evitar_deseleccion y def mantener_seleccion debería de bastar, pero al parecer, sigo teniendo el mismo problema.

La selección en un listbox está asociada con el portapapeles, cuando seleccionas un item el texto se copia al portapapeles. El proceso sigue las especificaciones de la selección primaria del sistema de ventanas X11, dónde el búffer solo contiene la última selección realizada. Cuando el foco se pierde la selección también lo hace.
Simplemente evita este comportamiento con el argumento exportselection del constructor de tkinter.Listbox:
lista_productos = tk.Listbox(
    ventana_combo,
    selectmode=tk.MULTIPLE,
    exportselection=False,   # <<<<<<<<<<
    font=("Helvetica", 16)
)

No necesitas de la función mantener_seleccion ni de evitar_deseleccion (que ya era inútil por si misma ya que solo llamaba a mantener_seleccion).


Claro, el tema está en que si quisiera poner 85 no me gustaría estar cliqueando 84 veces la flecha para arriba, por eso al hacerle doble click en el número para cambiarlo y poner 85 se deseleccionaba los productos

@Martin ¿has probado el código? Al menos en mi caso las selecciones no se pierden hagas click donde hagas, incluido hacer click en el spin para ingresar el número manualmente como comentas. He actualizado el gif de mi respuesta para que lo muestre. Si en tu caso no ocurre eso con ese código supongo que el problema es dependiente del sistema operativo y su gestor de ventanas de turno...
